# How to pass value from view to controller's action method parameter

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working in `MVC5` with `Kendo UI` and `jquery`. I have bind a multielect textbox with datasource and on button click I want to pass all selected values to controller action method parameter.Below is my code.

In my view:

```
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            dataTextField: "fullName",
            dataValueField: "Email",
            select: onSelect
        });

    var selectedValues = [];
    function onSelect(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[e.item.index()];
        selectedValues.push(dataItem.Email);
    }

    $("#btnshare").click(function () {
        var txtVal = selectedValues;
        window.location.href = "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ShareEmail", "Share", new { @multiselectemail = ViewBag.multiselectemail }))";
    });
```

IN Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ShareEmail(string multiselectemail)
    {         
        return null;
    }
```

But I never getting values in my parameter. What I am missing? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the rendered HTML of your `Url.Action()`?

Comment: That is blank page because I am currently returning null. I want to check only parameter value in ShareEmail method.

Comment: I mean, what is the rendered HTML of the page containing your JavaScript code? More specifically, this part `window.location.href = "@Html.Raw(...)";`.

Comment: Ohhh Sorry about that.It is returning "/Power/Search/Share/ShareEmail"

Comment: Why are you using `@html.raw`? remove it

Comment: I also tried it without html.raw.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I prefer to use *change* event and save every change in multiSelectList. Anyway my approach can be used for button click aswell.

```
 $("#btnshare").click(function () {
      var data = JSON.stringify({
           selectedValues: $("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect").value() // it returns all selected items
      });

      RunAsynchronousRequest("/ControllerName/ActionName", data, function (json) {
           //here I usually show some notification about success
           });
    });
```

Note that *RunAsynchronousRequest* is my helper method in shared js file which just run ajax request, which looks like this

```
function RunAsynchronousRequest(url, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success: function (json) {
        successCallback(json);
        },
        error: function (data) {
        errorCallback(data);
        }//,
        //async: false // in case you want it synchronously
    });
}
```

the code executed on button click can be also used in change event of multiselectlist.

And controller looks like you know it..

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ActionName(int[] selectedValues)
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to pass more than one items, you can not send it via query string. you should be posting it using HttpPost.

To post this via HttpPost, you can do a workaround like this.

**Step 1:** Create a dummy form in your page (If you don't already have one)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateStudent","Home",FormMethod.Post,new { id="myForm"}))
{
   <input id="btnSubmit" type="button"/>
}
```

**Step 2:**  When you get all your emails from your multitextbox, create an input field inside your form with the name `emails` and append that to the form. then submit the form.

```
var items = ["shyju","scott"];
$.each(items, function(ind, item) {
    $("#myForm").append("<input type='text' name='emails' value='" + item + "' />");
});
//Submit the form
$("#myForm").submit();
```

Now we need to make sure that we have our action method which accepts a collection of strings as parameter. **The parameter name should match same as the name we gave for our hidden elements**.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShareEmail(List<string> emails)
{
    // do something with the emails

    return View(emails);
}
```